# PIVOT not working Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

T-SQL code:

```
SELECT iCarrierInvoiceDetailsID, [1],[2],[3]
FROM [GroundEDI].[dbo].[tblCarrierInvoiceDetails]
PIVOT(MAX(dTotalCharge) FOR iCarrierInvoiceHeaderID IN ([1],[2],[3]))AS P
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: I din't get any syntax error.

Comment: Looks correct; is that the actual code you use when you get the error?

Comment: Seems to work just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c84a29/2

Comment: when i try this in my SSMS -> i get no error message! are you sure it's from this command?

Comment: just add this statement in derived table

Comment: Are you sure you had the whole statement selected when you clicked execute? often i have a bone head move where i forget to select a ) at the end of the line when i have a window open with multiple statements and i just want to run one. seems alright to me as well.

Comment: Yes this was copy and pasted. I just double checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to directly select the pivot columns from the table itself and not the pivot. You will need to do something like this:

```
SELECT p.[1],p.[2],p.[3] 
FROM 
(SELECT iCarrierInvoiceHeaderID
       ,dTotalCharge
FROM [GroundEDI].[dbo].[tblCarrierInvoiceDetails]) t
PIVOT(MAX(dTotalCharge) FOR iCarrierInvoiceHeaderID IN ([1],[2],[3])
)AS P;
```

Comment: It looks like it works but now i have a compatibility issue.

Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.

Comment: It is strange that the other one does not work. I fashioned it after 70-461 Training Kit Book

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think you can select your pivot columns ([1],[2],[3]) directly from the table like you have above. Since these are values in your `iCarrierInvoiceHeaderID` column, they would need to be pivoted before you can select them. Maybe I am not aware if it is possible to select directly from the table like you have it. As far as the compatibility_level goes, check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483372/incorrect-syntax-near-pivot

Comment: If you felt this answer was helpful and answered your question, please feel free to mark it as "accepted answer". This would also encourage other people to answer your questions in the future. Thanks!