# Pivot - how to sum and calculate the outcome

Tags: sql, select, pivot

I am sure this is a quick one, but tried everything, well apart from the answer. I have a pivot script which works fine, apart from the result in the columns, I need to divide by 100. So result / 100
Script is

```
SELECT 
USERID AS UserId,APPOINTMENTDATE,
isnull ([1],0) as'other',isnull ([2],0) as 'Medicare'
FROM 
(SELECT invoices.USERID, APPOINTMENTDATE,
[total],PAYERCODE,users.LOCATIONID
FROM APPOINTMENTS
where 
APPOINTMENTDATE between '2017-01-22' and '2017-01-23'  
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
Sum(total)
FOR PAYERCODE IN ([1], [2])
) AS PivotTable;
```

So what I would like to do is :
Sum(total) change to something like Sum(total/100)

Any thoughts..
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Added this sample as it works. Heres the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8eef1/1/0

The issue with your sample code is that you are trying to do a select on the table itself rather than the Pivot. You will need to define your columns inside your 'SourceTable' and then Pivot the PayerCode and then do your Select * FROM (Sourcetable Pivottable)

```
 drop table TestingPivot     
 Create table TestingPivot
 ( Total INT,
  Payercode INT,
  LocationID INT,
  UserID INT,
  Name VARCHAR(100) )

   Insert into TestingPivot values(100, 1, 1, 1, 'Ryan')
   Insert into TestingPivot values(200, 2, 2, 2, 'Mike')
   Insert into TestingPivot values(300, 3, 3, 3, 'John')

  Select * from (
  Select Total/100 as NewTotal, PayerCode, UserID, LocationID, 
  case when PayerCode = 1 then 'Other'
       when PayerCode = 2 then 'Medicare'
       else ''
       end as Type


   from TestingPivot
       ) as t
       Pivot
       (
         Sum(NewTotal) 
         FOR PayerCode IN  ("1","2")
        ) as P;
```

Comment: HI. Sorry that is doing the same as what I got which was Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '/'.

Comment: If that is the case, divide the total at your select and then you pivot the SUM. Should be the same Math. Editted.

Comment: Nope, that throws errors. Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
No column name was specified for column 3 of 'SourceTable'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'total'. tried a few variations...

Comment: It has to be the way you are writing it. I tried it on my db and it worked 
  Select * from (
  select MemberAge *100 as NewTotal, MemberFirstName from [SCRATCH_Test].[Test]
 ) as Source
 PIVOT
 ( sum(Newtotal)
     For MemberFirstName in (Gloria, Lori, Nelson)
  ) as Pivottable

Comment: The test above is a *100 on the Age value. Rather than a /100 but its the same syntax. Please create a SQL Fiddle with your table and let's see where the issue is.

Comment: If you are having incorrect syntax issue. I think this is really the problem. Not that you can't divide the Total https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295523/pivot-not-working-incorrect-syntax-near