# T-SQL Pivoting not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I am doing some training on T-SQL database Northwind using SQL Server 2008R2.

I am trying to pivot some data using the query below but it keeps returning the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'WITH'. Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 16 Line 16: Incorrect syntax
>   near '('.

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
SELECT
        [OrderID],
        [CustomerID], 
        [Freight] 

FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]
)
SELECT 
    [OrderID], 
    [10248],
    [10249],
    [10250]
FROM PivotData
PIVOT( SUM(Freight) FOR [CustomerID] IN ([10248],[10249],[10250])) AS P
```

Best Regards,

Dan

Comment: what is your sql server version?

Comment: Hi Madhivanan the version is 2008R2

Comment: Is your query part of a larger query? Could you post the whole code if so?

Comment: no it's just this one, just testing pivot functionality.

Comment: If you do this select `SELECT @@VERSION` on the database you are running this query from, what does it return?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to CTE statement must be finished with semicolon `;`
*or* prefix CTE with the same semicolon e.g.

```
;with ctePivotData as
...
```

Comment: Are you running this script in SSMS window or from somewhat application?

Comment: It should work. Unless there are some other circumstances.

Comment: Hi Ivan check Jamie answer below i think he might have the solution

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  Although this may not be the answer in this case, it's easily the most common cause of the error message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted works fine, sounds like your database has come from an older source and is running in an old compatability level (and so not supporting the PIVOT syntax).

Run the following SQL and try again:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Northwind] SET COMPATABILITY_LEVEL 100
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510680(v=sql.105).aspx) for more detail. Theres also a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483372/incorrect-syntax-near-pivot) that will show you how to do it in the GUI

Comment: Hi Jamie, it makes sense what you are saying since the query seemed correct, anyway i wont be abble to apply that alteration because i am training at the work database and don't want to mess it.

Comment: Ok, can you take a backup and create a development database?

Comment: Jamie btw will this change affect other databases or the server?

Comment: I'd recommend to check out your actual compatibility level first and find out why it was set to the current value (from DBA or someone like him).

Comment: yeah i think is better, i will try the query later at night at home and post result here, thanks guys

Comment: Ok great, no problem. (The query won't change any other databases)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this on a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance without problems.

```
SELECT @@VERSION;
```

Result:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) 
    Jun 28 2012 08:36:30 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE #orders(OrderId INT, CustomerId INT, Freight DECIMAL(28,2));
INSERT INTO #orders(OrderId,CustomerId,Freight)VALUES
    (1,10248,1.22),(1,10249,1.5),(1,10248,.25),(1,10250,.75);
WITH PivotData AS
(
SELECT
        [OrderID],
        [CustomerID], 
        [Freight] 

FROM #Orders
)
SELECT 
    [OrderID], 
    [10248],
    [10249],
    [10250]
FROM PivotData
PIVOT( SUM(Freight) FOR [CustomerID] IN ([10248],[10249],[10250])) AS P;
DROP TABLE #orders;
```

Result (without errors):

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| OrderID | 10248 | 10249 | 10250 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|       1 | 1.47  | 1.50  | 0.75  |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

---

PS: I'm thinking the statement before the `WITH` does not end with a semicolon in your case, or you are using SSMS 2008 R2 to run a SQL statement on a SQL Server 2000 instance.